# Question is mark separating url and not getting it in view?

Tags: url, django-views

I am trying to pass a parameter in url named title and it contains question mark(?) in it. I am unable to get complete parameter. Question mark is not showing in my view.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the question mark separates the path from the [*query string* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). You need to encode it with [*percent-encoding* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), so the question mark is replaced with `%3F`, for example:

```
somehost.com/foo/bar%3fqux/
```

Here the part after `foo/` will be seen as `bar?qux`.

That being said, often one wants to avoid these, since it will result in "*ugly*" URLs. Usually therefore a [*slug* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/glossary/#term-slug) is used, that removes such characters, and only retains characters that render nicely.